# MySQL 8 Get currently executed procedure name

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

When MySQL 8 executes a procedure, is there any way to get the name of that procedure being at the level of its code? 
Is there any kind of magic/system variable that represents name of the procedure?

Comment: You can create a log kind of thing to insert in a table when sp is being executed.

Comment: @James how to get stored procedure name when creating that log?

Comment: so why you need the name of sp? is it to track how many times it was executed or what Input parameters were given as a variable?

Comment: @James very close, I want to have a table in DB with simple log of every procedure execution - its name and the time it took it to complete a task. I would like not to hardcode the procedure name but get it from a `magic` variable or by selecting some system table. I also don't want to pass the procedure name as parameter to the procedure name (makes no sesne to me).

Comment: So you don't need the IN variables too?

Comment: the stored procedures use input parameters, but storing them is not an issue for me. I can't get currently executed procedure name to get it inserted to log table in DB.

Comment: So i have a idea but you need to hard code the sp name inside every sp you can also get the in variables parsed to it.

Comment: Unlucky the whole point is to not hardcode stored procedure name but get it from somewhere if possible.

Comment: If you have enterprise edition can try Audit log